# C# - Visual Studio 2013 - Not compiling in Greek Language

Tags: c#

I have a solution in C# with Windows Forms. The property of a form is set to:

Font: Microsoft Sans Serif, 8.25pt
Design: Language-Greek, Localizable-True

I had written the text, labels etc in English and translated them to Greek.

When making the compilation the debug exe is giving the previously English texts.

Is there a way to have the "greek" version of it?

I assume this has to do with the encoding and all.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you perhaps reduce your form to just one child control and post the code in `InitializeComponent`? And what do you mean by "the previous English texts"? Are they still stored somewhere? Where? And where are the Greek translations stored? Please update your question to include all this information.

Comment: I believed the case would be the localizable attribute but as it appears VS can get the Greek typing and encoding just by switching to the language preferred.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have Languare or Localizable set to Greek and True.

This is used in special cases when part of the code will automatically transformed.

At the question asked, you need to write your text in Greek as normal (change the language of your OS).